# How to connect an oracle database installed in Unix to VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, unix

I have created an application in vb.net which retrieves all email addresses stored in an Oracle database and sends email to them. In this case, the oracle database is installed on Windows platform.
Is there any way of doing the same thing if the Oracle database is in Unix?
Please help.

Comment: Is there a network between windows and unix, if So, yes you can! Your `ODBC` configuration should be provided with the host name and the oracle _sid_ you attempt to connect.

Answer (score 0):

For communications between Oracle and .net (VB.Net or C#) oracle provides a driver named ODP.Net :
[Oracle Data Provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)

You can use the driver regardless the host of the oracle database.

If you are using MSDAORA note that [this driver is obsolete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Windows. Avoid
>   using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify
>   applications that currently use this feature. Instead, use Oracle’s
>   OLE DB provider.

Comment: Is there a way of doing the same if I'm using OLE DB for establishing the connection, because I've used OLE DB in my application?

Comment: Yes it should be fine. What driver do you use for the moment ?

Comment: I am using MSDAORA i.e. the OLE DB Provider for Oracle, if thats what you're asking

Comment: so what should be my connection string if the Oracle database is on a different system? Please give me an example of the connection string, I'm having difficulty as to what to mention in the 'Data Source' field?

Comment: You could define the connection in the [tnsnames.ora](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora) file an use this alias as datasource